# Unexpected results with HashSet.Contains and custom IEqualityComparer

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, hashset

I must have some sort of misunderstanding with respect to using a custom comparer with a `HashSet`. I collect a lot of different types of data that I store intermediately as Json.  In order to operate on it I am using Json.NET, specifically `JObject`, `JArray`, and `Jtoken`.

Generally I add a bit of metadata inline to this stuff at collection time, and it is prefixed with "tbp_".  I need to know if a particular bit of data, represented as a `JObject`, has been collected before (or not).  In order to do so I have a custom `IEqualityComparer` that extends the implementation provided by Json.NET.  It strips out the metadata before checking for value equality using the provided implementation:

```
public class EntryComparer : JTokenEqualityComparer
{
    private static string _excludedPrefix = "tbp_";

    public JObject CloneForComparison(JObject obj)
    {
        var clone = obj.DeepClone() as JObject;
        var propertiesToRemove = clone
            .Properties()
            .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(_excludedPrefix));

        foreach (var property in propertiesToRemove)
        {
            property.Remove();
        }

        return clone;
    }

    public bool Equals(JObject obj1, JObject obj2)
    {
        return base.Equals(CloneForComparison(obj1), CloneForComparison(obj2));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(JObject obj)
    {
        return base.GetHashCode(CloneForComparison(obj));
    }
}
```

I use a HashSet to track the data I'm operating on, since I just need to know if it already exists or not.  I initialize the HashSet with an instance of `EntryComparer`.  My tests are:

```
public class EntryComparerTests
{
    EntryComparer comparer;
    JObject j1;
    JObject j2;

    public EntryComparerTests()
    {
        comparer = new EntryComparer();
        j1 = JObject.Parse(@"
        {
          'tbp_entry_date': '2017-03-25T21:25:53.127993-04:00',
          'from_date': '1/6/2017',
          'to_date': '2/7/2017',
          'use': '324320',
          'reading': 'act',
          'kvars': '0.00',
          'demand': '699.10',
          'bill_amt': '$28,750.75'
        }");
        j2 = JObject.Parse(@"
        {
          'tbp_entry_date': '2017-03-10T18:59:00.537745-05:00',
          'from_date': '1/6/2017',
          'to_date': '2/7/2017',
          'use': '324320',
          'reading': 'act',
          'kvars': '0.00',
          'demand': '699.10',
          'bill_amt': '$28,750.75'
        }");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_Equality_Comparer_GetHashCode()
    {  
        Assert.Equal(comparer.GetHashCode(j1), comparer.GetHashCode(j2));
        Assert.Equal(true, comparer.Equals(j1, j2));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Test_Equality_Comparer_Hashset_Contains()
    {
        var hs = new HashSet<JObject>(comparer);
        hs.Add(j1);

        Assert.Equal(true, hs.Contains(j2));
    }
}
```

`Test_Equality_Comparer_GetHashCode()` passes, but `Test_Equality_Comparer_Hashset_Contains()` fails.  `j1` and `j2` should be treated as equal and are according to the results of the first test, so what am I missing here?

Comment: according to my understanding, hascode would always be unique for each object, right?

Comment: The tests only show that `GetHashCode()` works (meaning it returns the same hash for the two objects), but your `Equals` doesn't think that the objects are equal. Thatswhy `HashSet.Contains()` returns `false`. It not only compares the hash codes, but also checks `Equals()` if the hash codes are equal.

Comment: @EhsanSajjad no, that's not possible as there are more possible different objects than values of `Int32`. The hash code only provides a way to say "these two are different" faster if you have different hash codes. If two hashes are equal, you still have to check `Equals` to determine if the objects are _really_ equal. So a good hash distribution _can_ save a lot of `Equals` calls.

Comment: And the two objects are not equal, the time stamp `tbp_entry_date` is different.

Comment: @RenéVogt, take a look at the first unit test that passes.  I'm checking my implementation of equals after gethashcode in order to duplicate what the hashset is doing.  I guess that test is poorly named.

Comment: @Dimitri right, missed that....now it's getting strange...

Comment: Thank you everyone, @xanatos's answer below worked out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the signature of the class:

```
public class EntryComparer : JTokenEqualityComparer, IEqualityComparer<JObject>
```

otherwise the `GetHashCode()` and the `Equals()` that are used are the ones in the base class (that has a different "signature"... The base class implements the `IEqualityComparer<JToken>`, for this reason your methods aren't called by `HashSet<>`).

Then there is a small bug for the properties removal:

```
var propertiesToRemove = clone
    .Properties()
    .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(_excludedPrefix))
    .ToArray();
```

Better would be to "hide" the `JTokenEqualityComparer` and make it a private field, like:

```
public class EntryComparer : IEqualityComparer<JObject>
{
    private static readonly JTokenEqualityComparer _comparer = new JTokenEqualityComparer();
    private static readonly string _excludedPrefix = "tbp_";

    public static JObject CloneForComparison(JObject obj)
    {
        var clone = obj.DeepClone() as JObject;
        var propertiesToRemove = clone
            .Properties()
            .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(_excludedPrefix))
            .ToArray();

        foreach (var property in propertiesToRemove)
        {
            property.Remove();
        }

        return clone;
    }

    public bool Equals(JObject obj1, JObject obj2)
    {
        return _comparer.Equals(CloneForComparison(obj1), CloneForComparison(obj2));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(JObject obj)
    {
        return _comparer.GetHashCode(CloneForComparison(obj));
    }
}
```

Comment: Good call on `ToArray().`  I previously was selecting the string property names and projecting them `ToList()`, decided that was redundant since I could just use the properties themselves, and changed it without testing.  Doh.  Your suggestion to alter the signature worked, I have some learnin' to do!  Thanks for the help.